# How to only check pods in not Running/Completed status from a kubernetes namespace during a given time with bash

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I would like to check the status of pods that are not Running/Completed from a kubernetes namespace for 900 seconds and exit the script once the 900 seconds have elapsed if these pods are still not running/completed

Here is my script, which works except the exit of the script itself :

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMESPACE=$1
STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
status=false
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)); do
    result_getpods="$(kubectl get po -n ${NAMESPACE} | grep -v -E 
'Completed|Running' | { grep -v -E 'RESTARTS' || true; })"
    if [[ "$result_getpods" != "" ]]; then
        echo "Pods status for ${NAMESPACE}"
        kubectl get po -n ${NAMESPACE} | grep -v -E 'Completed|Running|Evicted' | grep -v -E 'RESTARTS'
        echo "$(date +%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S). Some pods are still not running."
        sleep 10s
        ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
        elapsed="$((ENDTIME - STARTTIME))"
        echo "$elapsed seconds elapsed."
        status=false
    else
        echo "Pods status for ${NAMESPACE}."
        kubectl get po -n ${NAMESPACE}
        ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
        elapsed="$((ENDTIME - STARTTIME))"
        echo "It takes $elapsed seconds to complete this task."
        echo "Deployment success."
        status=true
        break
    fi
done

if [[ "$status" == "false" ]]; then
    badstatus="$(kubectl get po -n ${NAMESPACE} | grep -v -E 
'Completed|Running|Evicted' | grep -v -E 'RESTARTS' | wc -l)"
    echo "$(date +%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S). $badstatus pods are still not 
running"
    exit -1
fi
```

Comment: Eliminate a whole class of misunderstanding your code by using `my_namespace=dummy; .... kubectl get po -n "$_my_namespace"`  etc. Also check your code at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: Is another language a choice?  There are [Kubernetes client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) for most popular languages.  This problem would reduce to "watch pods, checking their status, and exit after 15 minutes".

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve? What's your use case? Do you need to perform response actions? Simply configure a Prometheus query to monitor the status of Pods and trigger an alarm if the Pending status persists after 900 seconds.
(Assuming the cluster is monitored)

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. The goal was to check all pods of a namepsace in a different status as Running/Completed from a bash script in Gitlab during a time and exit the script if there are some pods in wrong status after this time. The if condition was not in the good place in the complete script.